# How to determine if text is written in the last row of the page with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, page-break

I'm using Apps Script to fill a google doc with many paragraphs.
Each paragraph has its header. Because the text is filled by itself by the script, sometimes a certain paragraph's header starts in the page's last row. I'm trying to avoid that.

I want to spot whether the last row I append in the paragraph before is at the end of the page (or even maybe in the last quarter of it) and if it is, to make a page break and move the next header to a new page.
Is there a way to do so?

Thank for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is currently not possible. It is not even possible which page the paragraph is contained in at all (
see respective [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/36755897))

### What you can do instead is to specify that all lines of a paragraph (including) shall be kept together

[image]

**To do it programmaticaly:**

- Enable the [Advanced Google Docs service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services)
- Update the [ParagraphStyle](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#paragraphstyle) of your newly created paragraph setting `"keepLinesTogether"` to `true`.

**Sample (provided you know the index of the new paragraph):**

```js
  var doc = Docs.Documents.get(documentId);
  var paragraph = doc.body.content[paragraphIndex];
  var request = {
    "updateParagraphStyle": {
      "paragraphStyle": {
        "keepWithNext": true,
      },
      "fields": "keepLinesTogether",
      "range": {
        "startIndex": paragraph.startIndex,
        "endIndex": paragraph.endIndex
      }
    }
  }
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ 'requests': [request] },documentId);
```